# 'SyntaxError: unexpected MATH' at mathematical modulo operator '%%'

Tags: coffeescript

According to http://coffeescript.org/#operators, `%%` is an operator for "dividend dependent modulo"

I have used the operator in this line:

```
 @startIdx = (@startIdx - 1) %% @capacity
```

Both `@startIdx` and `@capacity` are integers

But this line causes `coffeelint` to throw this exception

```
SyntaxError: unexpected MATH (coffeescript_error)
```

Is the syntax actually legit? Is it a bug of coffeelint? If so, how can I turn off this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with older version of coffeelint (1.0.8)

Here is a workaround: wrap the lines with these lint directives:

```
    # coffeelint: disable=coffeescript_error
    # coffeelint: disable=space_operators
    @startIdx = (@startIdx - 1) %% @capacity
    # coffeelint: enable=coffeescript_error
    # coffeelint: enable=space_operators
```

At the end it is resolved by upgrading to more up to date version of coffeelint